# Getting an error during evolution slider plugin activation in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed the revolution slider plugin in WordPress but I can't activate it and I'm getting the error below:

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/j8fkjve3kft3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php:69
Stack trace:
 #0 /home/j8fkjve3kft3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(424): RevSliderBaseAdmin::addMetaBox('Revolution Slid...', '', Array, NULL)
 #1 /home/j8fkjve3kft3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(72): RevSliderAdmin->addSliderMetaBox()
 #2 /home/j8fkjve3kft3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(44): RevSliderAdmin->init()
 #3 /home/j8fkjve3kft3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(150): RevSliderAdmin->__construct('/home/j8fkjve3k...')
 #4 /home/j8fkjve3kft3/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2050): include('/home/j8fkjve3k...')
 #5 /home/j8fkjve3kft3/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php(175): plugin_sandbox_scrape('revslider/revsl...')
 #6 {main} thrown in /home/j8fkjve3kft3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php on line 69
```

My PHP version is 7.2

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the maker of the plugin with the error message.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260187/how-can-i-fix-fatal-revslider-error-in-dashboard-after-upgrading-to-php-7